# WebSecurity.Login failure reason

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, authentication

I enabled the confirmation feature with WebSecurity.Login method, it all works fine and when a user has not confirmed his account yet it fails the login as it suppose to but how can I know why the failure as occurred?

I would like to separate between a failure due to incorrect username / password and failure due to unconfirmed account but the login method only returns Boolean value

Answer (score 0):

Just add this check before login

```
if (!WebSecurity.IsConfirmed(userName))
       ModelState.AddModelError("", "The Account is not confirmed yet!");
```

Comment: This will return false no matter if the username / password is correct or not, so it will not give me the difference i am looking for...